# Windows 10 cannot access the specified device, path, or file when using full path to executable, running as Administrator

Tags: c#, windows, encoding, filesystems, windows-10

**Note** : I've replace the directory with `a` and the exe with `b.exe` and I've repeat every test I have made to make sure it's not a typing syntax.

I have a very simple piece code of which works perfectly from Windows XP to Windows 7.

```
var processPath = @"c:\a\b.exe" ; // this exe exists on my computer
Process.Start(processPath);
```

and also

```
Directory.Exists(@"c:\a\") returns false on Windows 10.
```

Since Windows 10 (I have not test yet 8 and 8.1) the first code will throws `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception` ("Specified file not found") and second  will return false. .

**I've noticed also that it's the same behaviour when I run "c:\a\b.exe" with the windows run window (Windows Key + R).**

Is there any workarounds to solve this issue? In preference, a solution which implies no recompilation.

**NB** :

- I'm running windows as Administrator
- **The user has access to the file (security attribute enable for everyone in the computer)**.
- `c:\b.exe` works !!
- I'm not looking for a solution like change your application working directory and run  Process.Start("b.exe").

Thank you all,

EDIT :

- **The specified path is not WRONG and the file is not missing.**
- Every user of the computer as Total control level acceess over the folder and the file (`a` directory and `b.exe`)
- Works when I put the exe on the root directory : "c:\b.exe"
- Same behaviour with .bat file with only "echo Hello inside"
- `Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\")))` display the directory `c:\a`

UPDATE :

Results of `icalcs c:\a\` :

```
c:\a\ Tout le monde:(OI)(CI)(F)
         BUILTIN\Administrateurs:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
         AUTORITE NT\SystŠme:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
         BUILTIN\Utilisateurs:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
         AUTORITE NT\Utilisateurs authentifi‚s:(I)(M)
         AUTORITE NT\Utilisateurs authentifi‚s:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(M)
```

Results of `icalcs c:\a\b.exe` :

```
c:\a\b.exe Tout le monde:(I)(F)
               BUILTIN\Administrateurs:(I)(F)
               AUTORITE NT\SystŠme:(I)(F)
               BUILTIN\Utilisateurs:(I)(RX)
               AUTORITE NT\Utilisateurs authentifi‚s:(I)(M)
```

"Tout le monde" means Everyone.

**UPDATE** :

On the last news, I'm able to do :

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\a\b.exe", somebinaries) ;
```

But I'm not able to do

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\a\b.exe") ;
```

Throwing 'System.NotSupportedException'. StackTrace is as follows:

```
   à System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String fullPath, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
   à System.IO.FileInfo.Init(String fileName, Boolean checkHost)
   à System.IO.FileInfo..ctor(String fileName)
   à ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) dans F:\MAPW10\Development\Sources\Tools\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:ligne 22
   à System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   à System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   à Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   à System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   à System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: maybe the file does not exist?

Comment: @robot9706 nice but the file exists and the user can access to the file.

Comment: I believe that having a file in the root of C:\ now requires administrative permissions to perform actions on it.  While you may be an administrator, the program might not be elevated to run with administrative rights.  I'd suggest running your program as an administrator to see if it changes anything.

Comment: @Pablo Honey I think paths are case sensitive, so the file you are trying to start does not exist. (For example if the folder is "ToolsAndUtils")

Comment: @Lunyx I have admin permission, I'm running as Administrator. Moreover the security attribute of the file allows everyone in the computer

Comment: Does the app work if you run it explicitly as `Administrator` (Right-Click-->Run as Administrator)

Comment: @Jaco : It's the same behaviour with (Right-Click-->Run as Administrator)

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change any part of the path to the util? A simple typo or something could suffice.... Hardcoding filepaths is always a bad idea btw.

Comment: @MrPaulch : I've checked twice with 2 .exe and a .bat

Comment: Maybe try to break down the path to parts and using File.Exists and Directory.Exists check the path parts (so "C:\", "C:\toolsandutils", "C:\toolsandutils\consoleapp.exe").

Comment: @robot9706 C:\toolsandutils\ Actually Directory.Exists fails but the directory exists and every user as total access to the directory

Comment: 1) Are you running VisualStudio in Administrator mode? 2) Are you sure the folder is called "toolsandutils" and not "ToolsAndUtils". I suggest you to navigate to the folder in a Windows File explorer and copy the path from the address bar and paste it in your code.

Comment: @PabloHoney Is there anything noteworthy about the directory? Did you just finish creating it and putting the files in it? Is it hidden? Is it shared? What do you get if you run `Directory.GetDirectories(...)` on it's parent folder? For sanity, can you post the entire Exception?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn Not hidden, not readonly. I will check Directory.GetDirectories(...)

Comment: Try deleting and re-creating the folder.  There may be a hidden/special character in the folder name.

Comment: @Sandra I tried with a new folder but it's the same behaviour !

Comment: @CoreyOgburn  the directory c:\toolsandutils is displayed with  Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\r\n", Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\")));

Comment: You definitely have something weird going on because `Process.Start(string)` will throw a FileNotFoundException if the file was really not found. Since you're getting Win32Exception then you're in some sort of really niche context. Or Win10 is being beyond weird, but I haven't experienced this bug on my machine.

Comment: [Let's continue this in chat.](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94446/process-start-fails-in-windows-10-when-using-full-path-to-executable-running-as)

Comment: Have you tried running chkdsk?  Those symptoms could be caused by file system corruption.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says that `FileNotFoundException` is thrown when `The PATH environment variable has a string containing quotes.`

Comment: @CoreyOgburn : Sorry for friday, I left home

Comment: @HarryJohnston Disk is OK I tried with other disk d:\a\b.exe, same problem

Comment: What is `Exception.NativeErrorCode` value?

Comment: Please enter `icacls c:\a` and `icacls c:\a\b` on the command line and copy-and-paste the output into the question.  Also, try disabling your anti-virus software.

Comment: @codroipo Exception.NativeErrorCode = 2

Comment: Have you already tried to repair the .NET Framework installation?

Comment: @codroipo : I repair it with NetFxRepairTool.exe. Still not working

Comment: Can you successfully get a new FileInfo on any other file, i.e. outside that directory?  What about another file inside that directory?  What if you rename the file to .txt instead of .exe?

Comment: Just because you are logged in as an administrator, it doesn't mean you are running with administrator privileges! But in this case, my vote goes to your AV software.

Comment: Also, while you probably won't **have** to change your app here, you _should_ change your app. Making your own folders off of the root is **bad practice**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I found it !!

It's some extra non-printable bytes added in file path when Copying / Pasting from **some labels in Windows 10 explorer**.

Consider this piece of code :

```
Console.WriteLine(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\a\"));
Console.WriteLine(new DirectoryInfo(@"‪c:\a\"));
```

These line looks the same and should not raise any exception (even if directory `c:\a` doesn't exist) but actually if you copy/paste the code above in an application, the second line will raise `NotSupportedException` with words : "*The given path's format is not supported*".

I've ended up checking .NET source code and I found method [StringExpressionSet.Canonicalize](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/util/stringexpressionset.cs,9962e430aeafa4ab,references) which raised NotSupportedException :

```
...
 if (path.IndexOf( ':', 2 ) != -1)
      throw new NotSupportedException( Environment.GetResourceString( "Argument_PathFormatNotSupported" ) );
...
```

And actually :

```
Console.WriteLine(@"c:\a\".IndexOf( ':', 2 )); //  results -1
Console.WriteLine(@"‪c:\a\".IndexOf( ':', 2 )); //  result 2
// Copy/Paste to test
```

---

### Where did I caught it ?

In order to not making any typing mistake, I'm used to copy directory path from Right Click to a file -> `Properties` -> `Security`

[image]

**You are warned now** !

Answer (score 1):

```
...SystŠme
...authentifi‚s
```

Obfuscating the directory and file name makes it very hard to help you.  But there's one obvious rock to look under, getting the accented characters mangled so badly like this should never happen.  The machine speaks French but the encoding that appears to be used is 1250, only used in Eastern Europe.  A very bizarre mismatch, especially so for a console mode app.

If the *real* `a` directory likewise contains characters with diacritics then whatever root cause behind the mangled  icalcs.exe program output could affect the file system name encoding as well.  Rough conclusion is that this machine is pretty sick and needs help from the geek squad to get better.

Comment: Ty. Actually these french characters are displayed correctly in the cmd console. I've lost the encoding when I redirect it to a text file with `icalcs c:\a\ > dump.txt`.

Comment: It still should never be 1250.  One more time: *please* stop obfuscating the real directory name.

Comment: I rename the directory and the exe to a and b and I've repeat all the previous test. c:\a\b.exe is the real directory name.

Comment: Just in case there's still an encoding issue, try something like `DirectoryExists(String.Join("\r\n", Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\")))`  Have you tried disabling your anti-virus software yet?

Comment: Bounties for warning in agressive way that it may be an encoding issue.